# Grunt globbing ignore all directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, glob

Say I have a directory structure and I have a grunt task that does something with source files:

```
src: [
  "foo/bar/**/*"
]
```

This will match all files and folders inside foo/bar.

For instance, if I have a grunt task that runs "this.files.forEach", all files and folders will be iterated over. I know I can just check if the item is a file by "grunt.file.isFile", but is there a way to specify in the globbing pattern to only match files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `filter` option which you can pass `'isFile'` to.

Based on the [gruntjs docs example](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function), your configuration should look like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  clean: {
    foo: {
      src: ["foo/bar/**/*"],
      filter: "isFile",
    },
  },
});
```

Not quite in the globbing pattern, but still more "declarative" than having to do a `this.files.forEach` with `grunt.file.isFile`.